# Background in Haxe/Pixi

Tags: haxe, pixi.js

I'm actually doing some exercises in Haxe, and i have a little problem with the background of my stage.

basically, when i create a stage i have to give it a color like this

```
stage = new Stage(0x3F7CB6);
```

I would like to set an image, and not a color, as background that is ALWAYS back and always cover ALL the Screen, and do not cover the other image elements how can I do that?

The only thing i found is a function that set the color of the stage, but there is nothing for an image

Is there something like the Z-index in CSS? Or what is the best practice?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to specify a background image using OpenFL or Flash but what you can do is add a child to the stage before everything else.

If you have already added displayable objects to the stage the simplest way is to call `stage.addChildAt(image, 0);`. This adds an image object that you've created to the stage at index 0 which will render before everything else on the stage.